# Encrypted Swap Causes Boot Crash

Tags: boot, encryption, swap

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now. I encrypted my home folder and the swap area and now when I select the first option in the boot loader the OS freezes. I tried reinstalling and encrypting on install and encrypting after install with the same effect.

A weird pattern of squares is shown on the screen and the keyboard is unresponsive(even numlk doesn't make the LED light up). I can boot by going in recovery mode and selecting continue booting normally but the graphics driver doesn't load and I have a very annoying resolutions.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I am running ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

You must not encrypt your swap disk, because it does not support encrypt.

As you know, swap is just supporter, not the disk space you're going to put files.